# Why the bars out of the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a div which contains bars(divs).

### **The problem is :**

The  bars seems out of the parent div but it should be in it.

The parent div id is ***block_gantt*** and it has scroll.

Everything is fine in *internet explorer* but in *google chrome* it is problem.

the screenshot is from *google chrome* (I do not want this):

[image]

**//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

the screenshot from *internet explorer*(it is correct)
[image]

### Here is my code:

```
<div id ="block_gantt" style="height:240px; width:880;" onscroll=" gantt_scroll();">

<div onclick="ShowItemDetail(160662);" style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute;margin-left:614px;text-align:left;float:left;height:28px;width:2896;" >
  <div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;z-index:1;text-align:left;background:#F1F1F1;width:2814px;height:28px;float:left;">
    <div style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute;z-index:2;background:#fea621;width:1094px;height:28px;float:left;text-align:left;">
    </div></div><div style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute;z-index:3; width:2896px;height:28px;float:left;text-align:left;font-color:#555555;left:3px;top:8px;">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 39% 
    </div>
   <div style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute;z-index:4;left:1094px; width:2814px;height:28px;float:left;text-align:left;padding-left:3px;color:#444444">
   </div>
   <div style="overflow:hidden;padding-left:5px;position:relative;z-index:6;width:70px;height:28px;float:left;color:#333333"> 
   </div>
</div>
...same for above
...same for above
...same for above

</div>
```

***my fiddle :***

http://jsfiddle.net/LFUah/2/

Comment: Post some code too... We didn't get anything ...

Comment: We can't help you fix the problem if we can't see/ modify your code.
Please provide the relevant HTML / CSS to reproduce this issue.

Comment: which code can I paste here? thanks for answer

Comment: set width to inherit and ooverflow to hidden

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar probably the one that is producing your issue...

Comment: try to set your DIVs  css overflow:hidden

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake you can see above code, I add already overflow:hidden

Comment: @Krishna I add code please look

Comment: Better wayn is to create a fiddle please make a jsfiddle demo. http//:jsfiddle.net

Comment: I edit my question you can see the fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/LFUah/2/ why the child div out of the parent div

Comment: @Krishna sorry I edit my fiddle you can see : http://jsfiddle.net/LFUah/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `position:relative` to your `block_gantt` div

Comment: sorry I see your answer now, should I add this to div propoerty?

Comment: you are welcom ... hard luck